# How do I fix 'No valid session available from this socket' during SocketIO handshaking in sails.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io, sails.js

I am using sails.js to develop the API to an iOS app and is using websockets for realtime communications. The problem is that I cannot get the socket io handshaking to work.

'No valid session available from this socket' error is shown in the console. When I Googled a bit I came to know that I need to set a valid cookie. As my client is not Browser based Javascript I cannot set any cookies.

I even set the `authorization: false` in `config/sockets.js`

Is there any solution to this ? Or was choosing Sails JS for this task a mistake ?

BTW these are some links I came across with this issue :

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1062
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/995
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1003

Comment: Does your app need session support?  If not, you can just ignore this error.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions

1. > As my client is not Browser based Javascript I cannot set any cookies.

   You definately can "set a cookie", you just need to make it manually :

   - intercept `Set-Cookie` header
   - parse it to retreive `sails.sid`

   Later, when you happen you make a request :

   - Pass the retrieved `sails.sid` to your request's `Cookie` header

   You can even find a [library](https://github.com/pillarjs/cookies) that makes this for you.
2. Just exclusively keep interracting with sails server **through** [the official client library](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js), it will handle all that logic for you. (make "REST-like" requests through it's sockets with helper methods, do not make true http requests outside)